# Not able to use installed libraries

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip

I have installed face_recognition model using command

> pip3 install face_recognition

and it is installed in my AWS instance. But while importing face_recognition in my jupyter notebook it is giving me import error.
Thanks

Comment: Check whether you're running the same python version in the notebook `pip3` is installing to: in the notebook, open the terminal and issue `import sys`, `sys.version`, `import site`, `site.getsitepackages()`. Then issue `pip3 -V` in the terminal and check whether the python versions and site packages dirs match.

Comment: Actually pip3 is installed in the python3 which was preinstalled in the instance so it is not linked to my jupyter notebook. So, I again installed face_recognition model in Anaconda environment using command pip install face_recognition as pip is installed while installing Anaconda3. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a python environment? you have to make sure that the python interpreter that is running your code is the same one that has the `face_recognition` requirement installed.